# Month picker issue in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, npm, next.js

I am trying to make a month picker using the library, [**react-month-picker**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-month-picker)

**Working** code in react: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-month-picker-forked-84rqr

And I have copied the same code into **Next Js project** (React SSR)
https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-bartik-o5miw but it throws the error as,

> invalid value of property "value" in month-picker

**index.js:** (Code is related to only month picker)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactMonthPicker from "react-month-picker";
import "react-month-picker/css/month-picker.css";

const MonthPicker = ({ range }) => {
  const [isVisible, setVisibility] = useState(false);
  const [monthYear, setMonthYear] = useState({});

  const showMonthPicker = event => {
    setVisibility(true);
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  const handleOnDismiss = () => {
    setVisibility(false);
  };

  const handleOnChange = (year, month) => {
    setMonthYear({ year, month });
    setVisibility(false);
  };

  const getMonthValue = () => {
    const month = monthYear && monthYear.month ? monthYear.month : 0;
    const year = monthYear && monthYear.year ? monthYear.year : 0;

    return month && year ? `${month}-${year}` : "Select Month";
  };

  return (
    <div className="MonthYearPicker">
      <button onClick={showMonthPicker}>{getMonthValue()}</button>

      <ReactMonthPicker
        show={isVisible}
        lang={[
          "Jan",
          "Feb",
          "Mar",
          "Apr",
          "May",
          "Jun",
          "Jul",
          "Aug",
          "Sep",
          "Oct",
          "Nov",
          "Dec"
        ]}
        years={range}
        value={monthYear}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        onDismiss={handleOnDismiss}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const range = {
    min: { year: 2020, month: 3 },
    max: { year: 2025, month: 2 }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MonthPicker range={range} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Seems like a simple issue but I couldn't figure it out where I am getting wrong.

Issue is it works in react [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-month-picker-forked-84rqr) but not in Next JS [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-bartik-o5miw).

Could you please help me to select the month and year from the picker?

Comment: As far as I can see from the docs, there is no way to set empty value. I think that `value` begin empty object is source of your error.

Comment: @radovix, Could you check this one https://codesandbox.io/s/react-month-picker-forked-84rqr ??

Comment: @radovix, Thanks for your reply.. Could you help me fixing it please?

Comment: That one is working not. Not sure how to fix that on next.js. Sorry.

Comment: Hey, can you provide us Next Js project that can be edited? Something like the link from few comments above.

Comment: You can use the fork option in the right side of that link..

Answer (score 0):

const [monthYear, setMonthYear] = useState({month: '', year: 0});